# MS teams Incoming Webhook usage issue

Tags: python, c#, microsoft-teams

I want to use incoming Webhook to notify a channel on teams and @mention someone.

I implemented sending messages to a channel from an external application, but how can I mention someone, I haven't found a solution.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: Could you please tried out the  [Outgoing webhook][1]


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook?tabs=urljsonpayload%2Cdotnet?
The Outgoing Webhook acts as a bot and search for messages in channels using @mention. It sends notifications to external web services and responds with rich messages

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks for your response. but I want send message use incoming webhook from external web services and using @mention function. Information is transmitted from the outside in, not from the inside out. how can I do it?

Comment: I'm looking for examples, so I don't have any code

Comment: Here is some Sample available :-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL#send-adaptive-cards-using-an-incoming-webhook

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#mention-support-within-adaptive-cards